# prevent gridView from expanding to fit landscape width

Tags: java, android, grid

I have a gridView with 4 columns of imgs. When phone is turned to landscape layout, grids of the gridView expand to fill the width, creating white spaces in between the img although the img stay at desired width. Is there a way to keep the grid view from filling width of screen when in landscape layout ?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 methods to do that:

1) Create layout for each orientation:

```
res/layout/....
res/layout-land/....
```

2) Only one layout for both vertical and horizontal orientation:

- set up GridView with: `android:numColumns="4"`
- your custom view item, always set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

with the second method, you may encount problem with high of item. Just  create your custom View and override `onMeasure`.

For example: I need a LinearLayout for my item and the keep my ratio `height/width = 4.5/4`, so I do the following custom:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    //..... constructor methods
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int scaleHeight =(int)( widthMeasureSpec/4*4.5);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, scaleHeight);
    }
}
```